# Spirit error handling: expectation point does not return the expected "what" value

Tags: boost, error-handling, grammar, boost-spirit

I'm using the Spirit error handling code from the article "Dispatching on Expectation Point Failures" at http://boost-spirit.com/home/2011/02/28/dispatching-on-expectation-point-failures/comment-page-1/, the last example there.  My "diagnostics" and "error_handler_impl" classes are pretty much the same as is found in the article, but I can post them if someone thinks it is necessary.

In the code below, the start rule in question

```
comma = lit(',');
comma.name(",");
start = lit("begin") >> ident > comma >> ident;
```

has an expectation point after the "begin" keyword.  In accordance with the article, I expected that a missing comma would cause error handler to be passed the qi::_4 value to be ",", which is the name of the comma rule.  Instead, it is passing "sequence", causing the error handler to print a default message rather than the informative "Missing comma after begin keyword".

An idea what I am missing?

```
template <typename Iterator, typename Skipper = ascii::space_type>
    class Grammar1 : boost::spirit::qi::grammar<Iterator, Skipper>
{
    public:

    typedef boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper>  rule_nil_T;
    typedef boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, string()> rule_str_T;

    // structs from Rob Stewart's above-mentioned article
    diagnostics<10> d1;
    boost::phoenix::function<error_handler_impl> error_handler;

    rule_str_T ident;
    rule_nil_T comma;
    rule_nil_T start;

    Grammar1(void) : Grammar1::base_type(start)
    {
        ident  %= lexeme [ qi::raw [ (qi::alpha | '_') >> *(qi::alnum | '_') ] ];
        comma = lit(',');
        comma.name(",");

        start = lit("begin") >> ident > comma >> ident;
        d1.add(",", "Missing comma after begin keyword");
        on_error<fail>(start,
            error_handler(ref(d1), _1, _2, _3, _4));
    }

    ~Grammar1(void) { };

    void parseInputFile(Iterator itr, Iterator itr_end)
    {
        bool r = phrase_parse(itr, itr_end, start, ascii::space);
        if (r && itr == itr_end)
        {
            std::cout << "Parsing succeeded\n";
        } else
        {
            string rest(itr, itr_end);
            std::cout << "stopped at: \": " << rest << "\"\n";
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Thanks, adding parentheses as follows to "start = (lit("begin") >> ident > comma) >> ident;" fixed the problem.